# Is there a shortcut to comment and uncomment in emeditor?

Tags: emeditor

In vscode ,
ctrl+/ can comment ,
and can also uncomment ,
does emeditor support this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> to comment, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment. You can always change the keyboard shortcuts.

If you need to toggle Comment/Uncomment, you will need to write a macro like this:

```
s = document.selection.Text;
if( s.length == 0 ) {
    s = document.GetLine( document.selection.GetActivePointY( eePosLogical ) );
}
if( s.length >= 2 && s.substr( 0, 2 ) ==  "//" ) {
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4372);  // Uncomment
}
else {
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4371);  // Comment
}
```

This macro assumes the first two characters of a comment line is `//`.

Comment: good example!thanks!  there is a issue when i run it : it response slowly;  in addition it need to specify different comment prefix for different file extention, and some file use /* 
  */ as comment  string, it is difficult for non-programmer , it will be good if emeditor implement it 